# Save and Load data from a .txt file (using ArrayLists)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn how to save and load data from an ArrayList
(I know I should use a database but I'm a beginner).

I have the following problem that I want to solve:

[image]
I'm trying to create a WindowsFrom Application that allows me to save someone's mobile number. The Add button should Add the user that I put using my `textboxes`, inside a file and in my ArrayList. The remove button must remove him (if he exists).

This is how I approached the problem.

At first I created a class Person:

```
class Person
{
    private string name, areaCode, number;

    public Person(string nom, string code, string numero)
    {
        name = nom;
        areaCode = code;
        number = numero;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public string getAreaCode()
    {
        return areaCode;
    }

    public string getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
```

There is nothing too complicated about it. It simply take the `name` of the person, his `areaCode` and his `number`.

Then in my `public partial class Form1 : Form` I declared my ArrayList and an index `i` to it.

```
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
    // I know using a List (or HashSet) is better, but my teacher wants us to use
    // an ArrayList.
    private int i = 0;
```

Then I created 2 functions. One to save the data that I have in my ArrayList inside a `.txt` file. The other one is to load the data in the `.txt` file inside the ArrayList (in case we closed the program).
Here is my Save function:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("Saved_Files.txt");

        foreach(Person p in data)
        {
            sr.WriteLine(p.getName() + p.getAreaCode() + p.getNumber());
        }

        sr.Close();
    }
```

What I did here is creating a `StreamWriter` (since I want to write the data inside my ArrayList in a `.txt` file) then, because I know that all the elements inside my ArrayList are from the type `Person`, I did a foreach loop so that I can save the `name`, the `areaCode`, and the `number` of each `Person` I have in my ArrayList inside the `.txt` file. Then I close my `StreamWriter` to avoid having an `Already in use Exception`.

Then there is my Load function:

```
    private void load()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Saved_Files.txt");

        while(sr.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            data[i] = sr.ReadLine();
            i++;
        }

        sr.Close();
    }
```

Again nothing too crazy. What I did here is creating a `StreamReader` (since we want to read the data from the `.txt` file and put it in the ArrayList) then I did a `while` loop so that all the `Persons` in the `.txt` file will be integrated inside the ArrayList (I'm assuming here that one line = one `Person` since a `Person` is defined by its `name`, `number` and `areaCode`). Then I increment `i` to know at what index I am. And finally, I close my `StreamReader` to avoid an Exception.

Now I was prepared to implement my `ADD` button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person(textBox2.Text, comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(), textBox1.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.i; ++i)
        {
            if (data[i] == p) // To avoid duplications
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                data.Add(p);
            }
        }

        Save();
    }
```

In this button, I create a Person and give it a `name`, `areaCode`, `number` (they come from my `textboxes` and `combobox`. Then I do a `for` loop and make sure that the Person I am trying to put in my ArrayList in not already in there. Then I `Save` this person in my `.txt` file.
Here is my first problem. When I do this my `.txt` stays empty no matter what.

My second problem is in the Remove button:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person(textBox2.Text, comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(), textBox1.Text);

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove the following Client?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            data.Remove(p);
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
        }

        Save();
    }
```

As made previously, I created a `Person`, then I created a `DialogResult` (just to make sure if the user really wants to remove the selected person). If the answer is yes, the person is removed. If no it does nothing. And off course, I save everything.

The problem here is that no matter what I put in my `.txt` file (manually), and try to remove it. It won't go.

Can someone please tell what I did wrong (and possibly how to fix it)?

I'm sorry if it was too long and I hope my demand is formulated correctly (excuse me for my poor english, I'm from France).

Comment: holy sh** ... no one have patience to read through all this lump of code. narrow down the problem and post only the needed code block

Comment: Sadly this is the needed code :/ If I post less than that you won't be able to understand what I was trying to do. And if I remove the explanations, it might even take more time to you to understand :x. I'm sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have time to go in much detail, but i'd highly advise you to look into [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) which give you the possibility to have get/set accessors, this will take some of the need code to write a bit down, also making it clearer to read. Then, i'd advise you to look into [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) which will be a much more efficient way to store your data to and from.

Comment: You could also override `ToString()` in your `Person` class, so that when you try and access a `Person` as a string, you will have a correctly formatted string, making you only writing it once, instead of everytime you are trying to print/write or whatever

Comment: Without trying to address every issue here, your `Load` method doesn't work. You are adding `string` objects to the list, not `Person` objects.

Comment: I see, I will try what Antry suggested (that you for the Serialization link btw). And thank you Mark for pointing me out that I was adding a `string` to the List.

Comment: In addition to the previous given hints. Have a look at the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) while working with ressources which needs to be closed/disposed like the `StreamWriter` object. This ensures that you don't _'forget'_ releasing the ressource, avoiding exceptions and memory leaks.